Electron: Missing script: "start"
I'm making a first app with tutorial.

First installed Node.js on Windows 10

Then installed npm

Then created a folder for electron: C:\\electron-app

Then created a package.json: npm init -y

Then installed Electron: npm install --save-dev electron

Then changed the package.json to this:
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^31.0.1"
  }
}


Then created a main.js (empty)

Then I tried to start: npm start
PS C:\electron-app> npm start
npm error Missing script: "start"
npm error
npm error Did you mean one of these?
npm error   npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm error   npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts, run:
npm error   npm run



It should find the start script, on Electron quick start it says I can start it without any code in the main.js.
Error:
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.7.0
2 info using node@v20.14.0
3 silly config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config:load:file:C:\electron-app\.npmrc
5 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\nades\.npmrc
6 silly config:load:file:C:\Users\nades\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
7 verbose title npm start
8 verbose argv "start"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\nades\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-13T14_22_35_971Z-
10 verbose logfile C:\Users\nades\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-13T14_22_35_971Z-debug-0.log
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
12 silly logfile done cleaning log files
13 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "start"
13 verbose stack
13 verbose stack Did you mean one of these?
13 verbose stack   npm star # Mark your favorite packages
13 verbose stack   npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
13 verbose stack
13 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
13 verbose stack   npm run
13 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\run-script.js:79:13)
13 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\entry.js:74:5)
14 verbose cwd C:\electron-app
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
16 verbose node v20.14.0
17 verbose npm  v10.7.0
18 error Missing script: "start"
18 error
18 error Did you mean one of these?
18 error   npm star # Mark your favorite packages
18 error   npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
18 error
18 error To see a list of scripts, run:
18 error   npm run
19 verbose exit 1
20 verbose code 1
21 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\nades\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-13T14_22_35_971Z-debug-0.log


See the electron quick start guide here. Start should be:
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  }
}


How does changing the content of the start script alter whether or not it's found to begin with?

changed it but still the same issue

Update: I found the Problem, it is the Terminal in VisualStudioCode, i started it in command and it worked!
